# What's the meaning of "on good authority"?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

The news is **on good authority**.

What's the meaning of **on good authority**?

What's the meaning of **on** in the context?

I never have seen this type of sentence, plz help me to understand the actual sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning here is

> [based] on one or more reliable and knowledgeable authorities

Comment: 'On' mean—?......

Comment: It is an ellipsis. “Based on” gets shortened to “on.”

Comment: Can you tell me which grammar rule it follows?